# strike out unification ($\sqcup$)

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I need to denote that two varibles do not unify. `A \not \sqcup B` produces an unpleasant result:

[image]

Is there a symbol where the strikeout line is centered likd in $\neq$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe using `\slashed` or `\centernot` (as egreg suggests)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}

\[A \sqcup  B\]
\[A \mathbin{\slashed{\sqcup}}  B\]
\[A \centernot\sqcup  B\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also suggest `centernot`

Comment: @egreg of course, thanks. In this case, however, I think it looks a little better with `\slashed` :-)